# Ajax basic authentication using Cordova prompting for credentials

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, cloudant

I am building a mobile app using Cordova and Cloudant.  For this I need to make a POST request using ajax.  I am using basic authentication with headers `useCredentials=true` as required by Cloudant. However this gives me 401 on android device.  When emulating on browser it gives me a login screen.

Below is my ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  accept: "application/json",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true,
  },
  authorization: base64basicAuthString,
  crossOrigin: true,
  url: http-url,
  data: jsonQuery,
  success: function(data) {
    //process data
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log("Error getting data. " + jqXHR.status + " " + error);
  }
});
```